# Given $f(x)=x^2-3x+3$, find the value(s) of $x$ such that $f(x)=13$.

Tags: functions

I need to find the values for this problem. I already tried to plug in the $f(x)=13$ and I keep getting the wrong answer. I am not even sure how to start this. The problem is:

Given $f(x)=x^2-3x+3$, find the value(s) of $x$ such that $f(x)=13$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: This surely means that you would require the quadratic formula. Do you know this formula?

Answer (score 2):

$f(x) = x^2-3x+3 = 13\\
f(x) - 13 = x^2-3x-10 = 0$

Do you know how to find the factor that polynomial and find its roots?

Comment: Yes, this helps a bit i didn't think to set it equal to 0, but im confused on why you put -13 in the front of the equation

Comment: Because it's the value of $f(x)$ minus $13$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to solve $$x^2-3x+3=13;$$ that is, $$x^2-3x-10=0,$$ so $$x=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{(-3)^2-4(1)(-10)}}{2(1)},$$ *i.e.,* $x=5$ or $x=-2$.

Comment: it looks like a question have a better chance for getting an answer if the attached profile photo of the OP is beautiful, i have a statistically strong  evidence.

Comment: @ahmad: if you want to do better then I suggest you find an avatar who looks more in need of intellectual assistance than Einstein and learn how to spell  "amateur". $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: @RobArthan first i said that, because i knew i will get somebody nervous, secondly even in my country its known that pretty women are treated differently so why are you upset ?

Comment: You're better off raising this in the meta site, @Ahmad, rather than my answer to a rather simple, unrelated question.

Comment: @Ahmad: I am not at all upset, but your comments have nothing to do with the mathematics in Shaun's answer and it would be a kindness if you spelled "amateur" correctly in your profile.